# GCP /etc/resolv.conf is not using on-prem DNS servers

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform

in a GCP Redhat VM, I added one of our on-premises DNS host to /etc/resolv.conf.   I added the DNS IP after 169.254.169.254.

When I try nslookup/ping a host that belongs to on-premises DNS, it does not resolve the hostname.  Wireshark shows that it does not lookup beyond 169.254.169.254.

When I switch the IPs in /etc/resolv.conf and put my IP first, then the host on prem works, but GCP VM host name don't.  In this case, 169.254.169.254 is used, but none of the domains in the search list is used.

my understanding is that every DNS ip will be used to resolve the hostname, also every domain in the search list will be used in the process.  but this does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: Your assumption that every DNS IP will be used is incorrect. DNS resolvers will stop at the first DNS server that if functioning. What you need to do is implement `Split DNS Forwarding`.

Comment: Your issue is related to generic resolv.conf configuration question and not GCP related. 
The default behavior for resolv.conf and the resolver is to try the servers in the order listed. As John Hanley mentioned the resolver will only try the next nameserver if the first nameserver times out. Please find the [serverfault link](https://serverfault.com/questions/398837/second-nameserver-in-etc-resolv-conf-not-picked-up-by-wget) for more information.

Comment: Apart from “Split DNS Forwarding”, you could also try [dnsmasq](https://serverfault.com/questions/872109/resolv-conf-multiple-dns-servers-with-specific-domains/872127) to resolve your issue. 

I would also request you to post your findings in ‘Server Fault’ as ‘Stack Overflow’ is for programming and development questions.

Comment: thanks.  I will give dnsmasq a try.